# Cannondale SAVE frame technology in entry price

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, parts, cannondale, giant

I'm wondering if the so called "SAVE" technology from Cannondale makes any difference in the enry-mid price such as Cannondale Trail 4? (they publicize as a micro-suspension technology). In concrete comparing with similar price-range bikes from other manufacturers such as Giant.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually I'm thinking to buy "Cannondale Trail 4" or "Giant Talon 1 LTD". Giant seems a better on components/parts, while Cannondale publicizes this frame SAVE technology which looks good as well --but I don't know if actually can be any difference while riding or just marketing or the difference is not appreciable.

Comment: My first reaction is "oh yay another buzzword from a manufacturer"    "micro anything" tends to mean "we built in this cool stuff and charge you more for it but you can't see it... its really there honest!!!1"   Personally I would test ride it and then make a decision based on fit and comfort.

Comment: Don't think I can ask for a test (at least for that price-range bike). Even doing test, I'm not enough expert to notice anything. I just pretended to know if this frame could be really superior because its "exclusive" technology from competitors which (as I thought) seems is not (at least in a big step). So I think will get the Talon from Giant because of better equipment (even though a little more expensive).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All frames flex to some extent due to impacts or road shocks or vibrations. Some frames are better at absorbing this than others. All frame designers engineer their frames to attenuate these imperfections in riding conditions appropriately (for control/comfort reasons) by varying the size/shape of tubes and their compositions

SAVE is Cannondale's marketing term for this engineering. It isn't really honest to call it a "micro-suspension" anymore than any other rigid bike -- its just the frame engineer doing their job.

In a complete bike, you also have to take into account the rest of the bike beyond the frame like the saddle, handlebars, fork, tires, etc. in order to determine how comfortable/controllable the bike is. This is what you should assess the bike on, not some random marketing term.

You should go for a test ride before deciding on a bike. You may find that a bike without some marketing term like SAVE is more comfortable or better value to you than one with that. Or, you may like a bike with it. It would not be advisable to base the decision on buying a bike based on whether or not it was marked SAVE (or equivalent from other manufacturers).